# Extract image frames from an MJPG file

Tags: image, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'm trying to extract image frames from a short clip of an IP cam. Specifically this clip.

```
http://db.tt/GQwu0nZ8
```

So, I'm trying to extract that frames with ffmpeg with this.

```
ffmpeg -i M00001.jpg -vcodec mjpeg -f image2 image%03d.jpg
```

I'm just getting only the first frame of the clip. How can I get the rest of frames? Can I use another tool to get that images?

Thank you

Comment: You can use my library which is probably better then HTTP grabbing the frames for various reasons... if the cam support RTP or RTSP https://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This may be too much but here's a short javascript program for Node.js https://nodejs.org/ that will strip all the readable frames out and save them as separate sequentially numbered  jpg files in the current directory.  Beware, even a short video clip can generate thousands of frames and the V8 javascript engine that Node uses is really fast so I recommend closing your file browser because it will hog resources trying to keep up.

***If the video file is too large to create a buffer for, Node will issue an error and exit.***
In that case the easiest thing to do would be to split the file into chunks with your shell utilities or a program like HexEdit.  http://www.hexedit.com/

Rewriting this code to process the file asynchronously would fix that issue but writing asynchronous code still gives me anxiety.

```
var orgFile=process.cwd()+"/"+process.argv[2]; //Grab the video filename from the command line
var fs = require("fs"); //Load the filesystem module
var stats = fs.statSync(orgFile);//Get stats of video file
var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];//Get video file size from stats
var fdata=new Buffer(fileSizeInBytes);//Create a new buffer to hold the video data
var i=0;
var fStart=0;
var fStop=0;
var fCount=0;
fdata=fs.readFileSync(orgFile);//Read the video file into the buffer
//This section looks for the markers at the begining and end of each jpg image
//records their positions and then writes them as separate files.
while (i<fileSizeInBytes){

if (fdata[i]==0xFF){
    //console.log("Found FF at "+i.toString);
    if (fdata[i+1]==0xD8){
        //console.log("Found D8 at "+(i+1).toString);

        if (fdata[i+2]==0xFF){
            //console.log("Found FF at "+(i+2).toString);
            fStart=i;
            }
        }
    }
if (fStart>0){
    if (fdata[i]==0xFF){
        if(fdata[i+1]==0xD9){
            fStop=i+1;

        }
    }
if (fStart>0){
    if (fStop>0){
    fCount++;
    fs.writeFileSync(orgFile+"."+fCount.toString()+".jpg",fdata.slice(fStart,fStop));   
    console.log (orgFile+"."+fCount.toString()+".jpg");
    fStart=0;
    fStop=0;
    }
}
}

i++;
}

console.log ("Wrote "+fCount.toString()+" frames.");
```

If you save the above code as mjpeg_parse.js an invocation example would be:

**Node mjepeg_parse.js videofile.avi**

Answer (score 0):

The command with `ffmpeg` works fine, but you need to specify mjpeg video as an input file. If `M00001.jpg` is a single jpg image, then you will get only one (the same) output image.

Comment: In fact, the IP cam returns that "image" as mjpg video. With the software of the manufacturer, you can see that image generated is a video.

Comment: @edsonlp1 As I see, it's MxPEG format generated by Mobotix camera. How did you get this image? Can you access the mjpeg stream via url `http://<CAMERA_IP>/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg`? If so, you can try passing this url to ffmpeg as input. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to decode live MxPEG stream with ffmpeg. But it can easily decode downloaded part of the stream (downloaded for instance using `wget 'http://<CAMERA_IP>/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg'`).

Comment: I get that image extracting from the storage of the camera. How can you extract the information and you know that it's MxPEG format? The stream via url doesn't work for me because I need the maximum quality and resolution on the image. Thank you

Comment: The jpeg image you uploaded has some [data in the comment](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdb.tt%2FGQwu0nZ8), from which we can see it's Mobotix camera and MxPEG format. You can access the stream through [HTTP API](http://developer.mobotix.com/#http_api) and choose [streaming parameters](http://developer.mobotix.com/docs/params.html) appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @edsonlp1 For example I googled [a random camera](http://58.93.69.127/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg) and I can see its [help page](http://58.93.69.127/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?help) through the HTTP API. I downloaded part of the stream with `wget -O vid.mjpg 'http://58.93.69.127/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg'` and now I can extract the image frames from `vid.mjpg` using `ffmpeg` command from your question.